# Can i pass a session data from a aspx page to a php page?

Tags: php, asp.net, session, variables

I need to add in a survey form to an old asp.net application. I tried using creating another asp.net application but the server doesn't allow.

the survey form will get the user's particulars from a database, after everything is filled up and validation is done, a submit will create an excel spreadsheet, send a email to the user and update the database.

However the web server is not running the page of the new application, error says that a virtual directory is not created for the application and i do not have the access to the IIS manager, i only have the ftp access.

I am thinking of using php to do the job instead. My plan is to pass the session("userid") of the apsx page and call a response.redirect(survey.php). From there the php must know which user had done the survey, so i need to pass a session variable from aspx to php so that i only who is doing the survey.

Is this method possible? If so, how can i pass that session variable?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a hacky solution. If you are modifying the ASPX to do the response.Redirect, surely you and put your logic there instead of creating a PHP solution alongside?

If you really want to do this (which I don't recommend), just pass it in the QueryString.

```
response.redirect("survey.php?userid=" + Session["UserId"]).
```

Comment: So do i just create a $Userid at my constructor? Like function __construct($UserId) {  ?

Comment: No, you would access it via `$_GET['userid']` and assign it to any local variable you please.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the session information in the database, to be shared, which would avoid showing the values in the querystring (unless you encrypted it). ASP.Net has a SQLServer mode for session which you might be able to use by querying the DB from PHP. Otherwise just a custom table with the usual expiry date, user id etc. could work.